# How can make a button behave like this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that is opened in bootstrap modal style form. This form has button. When It is clicked, alert box should show up. I use this this code.

```
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('".$this->session->userdata('message')."');";
echo "window.top.location.reload();";
echo "</script>";
```

Everything is fine after a **browser resend notification appear**.

My question is **how to make the button refresh the page just like when you hit enter in the address bar**?

My form flow :

form->button clicked->data sent to controller-> do process in controller->send processed data to model -> insert to DB -> returns message to controller->in controller echoing the alert.

Comment: Where is click event handled ?

Comment: (if I understand what you try to do) I would use AJAX to call a small PHP script that will return you the messages from the server. This way you dont need to echo js from php and the messages will always be the latest

Comment: the flow is look like this : form->button clicked->data sent to controller-> do process in controller->send processed data to model -> insert to DB -> returns message to controller->in controller echoing the alert.

Comment: I just want to change the refresh/reload. to the reload/refresh when you hit enter in addressbar

Comment: is the js inside the <script> tag being called by the button click?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen yes.

Comment: I think most of us are not getting what you exactly wants ..You need to to elaborate

Comment: @SixthSense actually it's simple. When I click a button the whole page is refreshed, just like when you hit enter on address bar.

Answer (score -2):

Put button inside a form like i have done here.

replace (put_your_link_here) with your page link

```
<form action="put_your_link_here">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" >click to refresh</button>
</form>
```